# Sample: Calendar for Play2.0- scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, fullcalendar

I need to add a calendar to my website for managing events and I found this [sample](https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java) but it's only for Java. I tried to make a scala version of it but I get stuck at some points.

So I was wondering if there is something similar to it but for scala version.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why can't you use it from Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pedrofurla already said, just use it from scala. It's one of the scala's pros -- you can seamlessly use java code.